# Custom email from module works on localhost, empty on live server (m2)

Tags: magento2, email

Any ideas? I send an email from my custom module, and it works locally (AMPPS), but on live server it does not work. It just sends an empty email (no subject and no content).

Controller file

```
namespace Lala\EmailRegistrationData\Controller\Index;

class SendEmail extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        // Sending email 
        $templateOptions = array('area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => $storeManager->getStore()->getId());
        $templateVars = array('store' => $storeManager->getStore(),);
        $from =  'general'; /* array('email' => "test@webkul.com", 'name' => 'Name of Sender'); */
        $inlineTranslation->suspend();
        $to = array('myemail@gmail.com');

        $transport = $transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('email_registration_template')
                        ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
                        ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
                        ->setFrom($from)
                        ->addTo($to)
                        ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
        $inlineTranslation->resume();
     } 
}
```

email_templates.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="email_registration_template" label="Send email registration data" file="email-registration-data.html" type="html" module="Mediq_EmailRegistrationData" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

Email template file:

```
<!--@subject New user registration form submit @-->
<h2>New user registration form submitted</h2>
```

Again, it works great on my PC (via AMPPS), but as soon as its on live server, I only receive an empty email - no subject and no body.

Any ideas?

Comment: What about your SMTP config ?

Comment: I am using magepal SMTP extension, which again, works on localhost, but on live server it just sends an empty email - from correct email.